# Using Dockerfile instead of the command docker exec

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops, gitlab-ci

I have the following setup in GitLab CI. I have a script which I use to build my application using php, composer and npm commands.

I want to replace the script with a single `Dockerfile`.

Here is the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$APP" = "webapp" ]; then
  docker exec -t cozact_app composer install && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app php artisan down && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app php artisan migrate --force && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app php artisan storage:link && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app php artisan droit:run && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app npm install;
fi

if [ "$APP" = "webapp" ] && [ "$ENV" = "test" ]; then
  docker exec -t cozact_app npm run dev && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app php artisan up;
fi

if [ "$APP" = "webapp" ] && [ "$ENV" = "preprod" ]; then
  docker exec -t cozact_app npm run production && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app php artisan up;
fi

if [ "$APP" = "webapp" ] && [ "$ENV" = "prod" ]; then
  docker exec -t cozact_app npm run production && \
  docker exec -t cozact_app php artisan up;
fi
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh

composer install && \
php artisan down && \
php artisan migrate --force && \
php artisan storage:link && \
php artisan droit:run && \
npm install

if [ "$var" = "test" ] ; then
  npm run dev && \
  php artisan up;
else
  npm run production && \
  php artisan up;
fi
```

Comment: Please provide more details on what you want do so we can help you !

Comment: I want to build my laravel app at once without executing these following commands "docker exec -t app composer install && docker exec -t  app php artisan down ...", I want all these required php artisan commands, npm and composer installation to be done within the Dockerfile

Comment: Are you using gitlab-ci to build you application ? I see that you are running you application in the script (`npm run dev` and `npm run prod`) do you want to run your application after you build it ? what does the build generate as artifcacts (files)?

Comment: Yes, I use gitlab-ci to build my application and I run npm run dev or prod for the consol.log

Comment: It generates a code_artifact.tar.gz which I extract using linux commands gzip and tar zxf within a folder called /APP
and I run this command afterward to build 
docker build -t $REPOSITORY:latest  --build-arg NODE_ENV=$ENV ./$APP

Comment: That NODE_ENV is the argument that I want to use within Dockerfile to distinguish between prod and test environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Multi-stage `Dockerfile`, and adapt it to your usecase.

```
ARG APP_ENVIRONMENT=dev

FROM composer:latest as vendor


COPY database/ database/
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install && \
  php artisan down && \
  php artisan migrate --force && \
  php artisan storage:link && \
  php artisan droit:run && \


FROM node:latest as frontend

RUN mkdir -p /app/public

COPY package.json webpack.mix.js package.lock /app/
COPY resources/assets/ /app/resources/assets/

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install && \
   npm run $APP_ENVIRONMENT

FROM php:7.2-apache-stretch
COPY . /var/www/html
COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/html/vendor/
COPY --from=frontend /app/public/js/ /var/www/html/public/js/
COPY --from=frontend /app/public/css/ /var/www/html/public/css/
COPY --from=frontend /app/mix-manifest.json /var/www/html/mix-manifest.json
```

This Dockerfile is composed of 3 stages:

1. vendor: it gets the composer packages and run php artisan commands (I am not a laravel expert. So make sure to only keep the `php artisan` commands that should run during the build and not during the run. `php artisan` commands that needs to run during the run should go in a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in the last stage)
2. frontend: It gets JavaScript files, download the packages and build the static files
3. The last stage in the run stage, it copies the code inside the image and gets the frontend and vendor files from the earlier stages.

> the Dockerfile accepts a build argument `APP_ENVIRONMENT` that you can pass in CLI to control which env you are building to. 
> And then in `gitlab-ci.yml` you can just run a

```sh
docker build --build-arg APP_ENVIRONMENT=production .
```

In you `gitlab-ci.yml` you'll have something like the following:

```yaml
job:
  variables:
    DEPLOY_VARIABLE: "default-deploy"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:                              # Override DEPLOY_VARIABLE defined
        API_ENVIRONMENT: "production"  # at the job level.
  script:
    - docker build -t --build-arg API_ENVIRONMENT=${API_ENVIRONMENT} "some-tag" .
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the issue composer install shows within gitlab-ci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRt3W.png)

This issue is related to a part that is mentionned in the composer.json file, I did comment it to make it work for me, but I don't know if there will be any further issues due to this omit

```
   "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).